# Authentication using React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, web

I'm working on a project using React in the front-end and Django in the back-end.
I Used the `useState` function in React to handle the `isConnected` variable.
my problem right now is that the `isConnected` takes the initial value whenever I refresh my webpage, which is false, this is my code :

```
const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(false)

useEffect( async () => {

    async function checkJWTValidity(){
      try{
        axios.defaults.headers.post['Authorization'] = "JWT "+localStorage.getItem("token")

        //fetching ME data from API
        const requestdata = await axios.post(
          utils.endpoint,{query: utils.meQuery}
        )
  
        //checking if the returned Data is NULL, if so, tokens would be deleted from localStorage.
        //else token variables will remain for its still valid.
        if(requestdata.data.data.me === null){
          const tokenItems = await getNewJWT(localStorage.getItem("refreshToken"))
          if(tokenItems.length === 0){
            localStorage.removeItem("token")
            localStorage.removeItem("refreshToken")
            setIsConnected(false)
            console.log("null")
          }
          else{
            localStorage.setItem("token", tokenItems[0])
            localStorage.setItem("refreshToken",  tokenItems[1])
            setIsConnected(true)
          }
        }
        else{
          console.log(isConnected)
          setIsConnected(true)
        }
      }
      catch(err){
          console.log(err)
      }
    }
  
    async function getNewJWT(refreshToken){
      const token = []
      try{
        //fetching refreshToken data from API
        const requestdata = await axios.post(
          utils.endpoint,
          {
            query: utils.refreshQuery(refreshToken)
          }
        )
  
        //checking if the returned Data is NULL, if so, tokens would be deleted from localStorage.
        //else token variables will remain for its still valid.
  
        if(requestdata.data.data.refreshToken.errors === null){
          token.push(requestdata.data.data.refreshToken.token.toString())
          token.push(requestdata.data.data.refreshToken.refreshToken.toString())
        }
        
      }
      catch(err){
          console.log(err)
      }
      return token
    }



    checkJWTValidity();
  }, [])
```

if there are any optimal solutions that I could do, please tell me!
Thanks

Comment: Does the `isConnected` eventually get set to true after your functions are run?

Comment: @shn, yes it does, every refresh, it takes false first and then true

Comment: And you want it to be automatically `true`? Assuming the JWT validation step is required, there may be an unavoidable amount of time where the stored token is unverified.

Comment: @shn well, it didn't cause any probs at first, but then when i try to acess my /Account page, it redirects me to the home page, for the isConnected is false because the page reloads ..

Answer (score 0):

Whenever refreshing the browser webpage, your component tree and state will reset to the initial state.

To keep a previous state after a page reload in the browser, you need to do any one of the following

1. Save state locally in localStorage or IndexedDB
2. or At the server-side to reload.

And you need to add code at initialization to check previously saved local state or server-state, In this way, you can restore your previous state.

Comment: Thank you for Answering, instead of checking if isConnected is true, I'm now checking if the token localStorage variable exists, do you think this is a good thing to do?

Comment: @AhmedZrouqui have a look at this documentation, it will help you more in this situation  https://hasura.io/blog/best-practices-of-using-jwt-with-graphql/

Comment: @AhmedZrouqui please upvote if you have been helped by answer or comments, I will really appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

If you have sub components that are reliant on the validity of the token you can block further rendering while `isConnected` is false. This way you give the token time to refresh or be confirmed.

```
const Auth = ({children}) => {
    const [isConnected, setIsConnected] = useState(false);

    useEffect(async () => {
        if (!isConnected) {
            async function checkJWTValidity() {
                // ...
            }
        }
    }, [isConnected]);

    return isConnected ? children : null;
};
```

I've also added the isConnected value to the dependencies array and put an if statement inside the useEffect.

There will always be a point in time where the default state is used, however short amount of time it might be. This is the nature of javascript and web apps.

Comment: Thank you for Answering, instead of checking if `isConnected` is true, I'm now checking if the token localStorage variable exists, do you think this is a good thing to do?

Comment: It depends really, but bear in mind that the existence of a token does not mean its valid, it doesn't even mean the refresh token is valid.